# My application is showing the wrong date

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datepicker

I have a `DateTimePicker` that is showing the wrong date, but only on a few computers.

This is what is happening. I have in the database '10/27/2015', but the `DateTimePicker` is showing '10/26/2015' only on some computers, and the others are showing correctly. I couldn't find what is wrong. I checked the date/time settings and everything looks the same. Any suggestions?

Here is how I am setting the `DateTimePicker` value:

```
If Not IsDBNull(dttable.Rows(0).Item("data")) Then
    dtp.Value = Format(dttable.Rows(0).Item("data"), "dd/MM/yyyy")
End If
```

Comment: You need to post some code.   Best guess is there time zone conversion going on here changing the date

Comment: If Not IsDBNull(dttable.Rows(0).Item("data")) Then
                                dtp.Value = Format(dttable.Rows(0).Item("data"), "dd/MM/yyyy")
                            End If

I didn't posted it before because I thought that could be the settings once this work fine in most of the computers

Comment: what is the value in the database that is displaying the wrong date

Comment: The [`DateTimePicker.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is a `DateTime`, so I would not recommend setting it to a string value (I'd also recommend using `Option Strict On`).  What type is the `data` column in the database?  Something like `dtp.Value = dttable.Rows(0).Field(Of Date)("data")` may work better, unless the column is a `datetimeoffset`, or something else.

Comment: in the database data value is 27/10/2015 and dtpicker show 26/10/2015

Comment: the data type is datetime